# How to use tsc with -b build and --outdir at the same time?

Tags: typescript, tsc

The command `tsc -b --outdir folderName` fails with `"tsc Compiler option '--outdir' may not be used with '--build'"` and all files are compiled to the src folder instead.

How to prevent this from happening? Same with `tsc --noEmit`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the tsconfig compiler option instead:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "folderName"
  },
```

and now with `tsc -b` the outDir is respected.